# Parse PFObject save results to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm looking to save values within from the `PFObjet` and save them to multiple `NSMutableArray`s. Let me explain. I'm download information from the `Partisipants` class within Parse. The `Partisipants` class contains multiple `NSString` values, such as `name`, `phoneNumber`, etc. I'm looking to scrape that information from the return value of the query, and add each instance of a new `objectID` to the `NSMutableArray`. Assume there are multiple rows, or `userID`s to scrape into the `NSMutableArray`.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Partisipants"];
    [query setLimit: 600];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded. The first 600 objects are available in objects
            self.objectsFromParse = objects;
            NSLog(@"%@", self.objectsFromParse);
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

**Edit**

This is my return result for executing this query (personal information was modified):

```
(
    "<Partisipants:S420zHiNFT:(null)> {\n    additionalDonation = \"100.00\";\n    emailAddress = \"somewhere@email.com\";\n    emergencyPhone = 12345678901;\n    hasArrived = NO;\n    name = \"James\";\n    phoneNumber = 12345678901;\n}",
    "<Partisipants:9BpoFxO1zx:(null)> {\n    additionalDonation = \"500.00\";\n    emailAddress = \"someguy@email.com\";\n    emergencyPhone = 12345678901;\n    hasArrived = NO;\n    name = \"Michael\";\n    phoneNumber = 12345678901;\n}"
)
```

Comment: Have you checked Parse's documentation?

Comment: So do you want an array of just the objectId's retrieved?

Comment: @nhgrif The documentation only shows how to complete this with an `NSArray`, and not an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @Logan I want multiple `NSMutableArray`s that each would store all the `name` results, or the `emailAddress` results, and so on.

Comment: Anything you can do to an `NSArray` you can do to an `NSMutableArray` as well, as it is a subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store emails, names, objectId's etc. each in new mutableArrays, you could do:

```
NSMutableArray * usernames = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray * emails = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray * objectIds = [NSMutableArray array];
for (PFObject * participant in objects) {
    if (participant[@"name"]) [usernames addObject:participant[@"name"]];
    if (participant[@"emailAddress"]) [emails addObject:participant[@"emailAddress"]];
    [objectIds addObject:participant.objectId];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your array of participants. Then loop over them and build your mutable arrays(nameArray, email array, etc). Note that this is a very bad approach if some of the participants data is optional. How would you signify no email address for instance? You can't use nil in arrays so you'd have to represent it using NSNull or an empty string...

Answer (score 0):

You may need help from KVC.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Object : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *objectId;

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

@end

@interface Object ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *dictionary;

@end

@implementation Object

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.dictionary = dictionary;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)name
{
    return self.dictionary[@"name"];
}

- (NSString *)objectId
{
    return self.dictionary[@"objectId"];
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Object *object0 = [[Object alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"name": @"victor", @"objectId": @"001"}];
        Object *object1 = [[Object alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"name": @"evan", @"objectId": @"002"}];
        Object *object2 = [[Object alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"name": @"gerry"}];
        Object *object3 = [[Object alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"name": @"tony", @"objectId": @"004"}];
        NSArray *array = @[object0, object1, object2, object3];

        NSArray *objectIds = [array valueForKey:@"objectId"];
        NSLog(@"%@", objectIds);

        NSArray *names = [array valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"%@", names);

        NSArray *filteredObjectIds = [objectIds filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != nil"]];
        NSLog(@"%@", filteredObjectIds);

        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [filteredObjectIds mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"%@", mutableArray);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Console log:

```
2017-11-03 16:33:29.092837+0800 Test[50097:3891576] (
    001,
    002,
    "<null>",
    004
)
2017-11-03 16:33:29.093079+0800 Test[50097:3891576] (
    victor,
    evan,
    gerry,
    tony
)
2017-11-03 16:33:29.093317+0800 Test[50097:3891576] (
    001,
    002,
    004
)
2017-11-03 16:33:29.093401+0800 Test[50097:3891576] (
    001,
    002,
    004
)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```